# Browser compatibility issues - :active button state making button disappear in Firefox, IE, and Opera

Tags: html, css, browser

new guy here.

I'm currently teaching myself HTML and CSS and have created a landing pages to collect e-mail address for a business I'm starting.  Unfortunately, though the "Submit" button work how I'd like it to in Chrome and Safari, it disappears when clicked in Firefox, Explorer, and Opera and the button remains invisible until the user clicks somewhere else on the screen.

This is the website: http://fanbeat.com.

Any help you could offer would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I believe it has something to do with your active background positon.  What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: When I click down on the button, the bottom button in this image - http://fanbeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/submitbuttons.png - should appear.  This function works correctly in Chrome and Safari, but when I click down in the browsers I mentioned it doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have no action in your form declared. If you define an action the button appears directly after the action takes place.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?  The form works as it is supposed to in all browsers; the only issue that I have is that the button's active state is not displaying correctly in certain browsers.

Comment: UPDATE: I see now that it has no action defined, but that was built into the code (it's a WordPress theme I'm messing with) and hasn't interfered with the form's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your positioning of the background image.  Try this:

```
.class:active { background: url(submitbuttons.png) no-repeat 0 -92px; width: 145px; height: 45px; }
```

The reason is you are trying to position the PNG at the bottom and not position the actual background image.

Comment: Thanks, Chad.  That correction seems to have partially fixed the problem, but not completely.  The button no longer disappears when I click down, but it now disappears once I release the click.  Any suggests for how to stop that from happening?

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to identify the problem and fix it.  Thanks again, Chad.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the background image on input focus. Remove that and your button works fine:

```
#content-blocks-wrapper input:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: @andres-ilich Thanks for your help, Andres.  I made that change, but it hasn't seemed to correct the problem for me.

Comment: @Max i can still see the style being added on your page from the `style-launch.css` sheet, `line 138.`

Comment: Ah, I see what you were saying now.  I made that change and it fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Max if the answer was satisfactory please mark it as such by ticking the green checkmark next to the answer you choose, to give closure to the question.